# laravel link href click to save some data

Tags: laravel

```html
 <a href="https://localhost/sample.pdf" class="btn-buy">Preview  Your File</a>
```

**here link click to open pdf its fine but i want to insert some data when click this link how to insert and how to pass data laravel**

Comment: where you want to insert some data?

Comment: when click link (example=>id,date and time) insert in mysql database

Comment: You have to create a new method in the controller to do the operations you want and return the file after the insertion completes, don't forget to change the `href` to the new route.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two methods

1: Using Ajax:
First insert your data then in the success redirect to your file .

2: using controller to redirect you to the file
use form to submit the data you want to controller then via controller redirect it to your file after adding data to database

something like this

```
    public function AddDataToDatabase(Request $request)
    {

        $datas=New DataModal();
        $datas->name = $request->name;
        $datas->address = $request->address;
        $datas->lastName = $request->lastName;
        $datas->email = $request->email;
        $data->save();


        $items=Attachments::where('id',1)->get();
        return redirect('Attachments/'.$items[0]->attachmentName);
    }
```

or Using Ajax

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: your_URL,
                data: {
                    'name':'your_name',
                    'id':'your_id',
                    'email':'your_email',
                },
                success: function(data) {
                            window.location = 'https://localhost/sample.pdf';
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
```

then in your controller create a new method like this:

```
    public function AddDataToDatabase(Request $request)
    {

        $datas=New DataModal();
        $datas->name = $request->name;
        $datas->address = $request->address;
        $datas->lastName = $request->lastName;
        $datas->email = $request->email;
        $data->save();

        return response()->json(['msg' => 'added successfully'],200);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a link, create form that contains the fields that you want to store in database. Make the fields hidden if they won't be filled by the user. Then submit the form to a controller. Store the data, redirect to a new path that will display the pdf.